# Rendering template code from Spring-MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, knockout.js

Here is the code of my knockout template:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="row-extension-template">
    {{each items}}
    <tr class="tr_element">
       <td><span>${name}</span></td> 
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

This piece of code is embedded in my jsp file.

When I see the html source-code generated by the server is look like this:

```html
<tr class="tr_element">
    <td><span></span></td>
</tr>
```

But I want this:

```html
<tr class="tr_element">
       <td><span>${name}</span></td>
</tr>
```

I want the text `${name}` to be written in the html generated. How can I do that with Spring-mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved with this:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="row-extension-template">
    {{each items}}
    <tr class="tr_element">
       <td><span><%="${name}"%></span></td> 
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

That way when I see the html source code I get:

```html
<tr class="tr_element">
    <td><span>${name}</span></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page is loaded by using a Controller and RequestMapping in Spring.  Find the method annotated with @RequestMapping that corresponds with your page.  You then need to add the name to the model within that method.

```
 model.addAttribute("name", "Some Name Value");
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

Write an object to the `Model` with key `name`, as in:

```
@RequestMapping("foo.do")
public String myHandler(Model model) {
    String name = "something";
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "foo";
}
```

Comment: i understand. but is there samething simpler? I mean. i have to do something like this model.addAttribute("name","${name}"). But, i have a lot of ${..}. Is there any way i can indicate spring mvc that must not process ${name}?